# Chainable function becomes a singleton. How to prevent

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Please note: this is a super-simplified version of my upcoming question.
After writing that question I decided to split it into a few questions.

I’m trying to implement a chainable function. What is the expected output does not really matter for now, but what **does** is the API I’m trying to provide with it.

First thing first I'm trying to implement a function that can be chained with itself.
Let’s consider a function that accepts a color as a string and outputs it by calling method `log()`.
However, if we call this function on itself (chain it) it should output **2** colors now. If we chain it 3 times - the `log()` method should output 3 colors and so on…

```js
function getColor(color: string) {
    if (getColor.prototype.color) {
        getColor.prototype.color = getColor.prototype.color + " " + color
    } else {
        getColor.prototype.color = color
    }


    return {
        log: () => {
            console.log(getColor.prototype.color)
        },
        getColor: (color: string) => {
            return getColor.call(getColor, color)
        }
    }
}

getColor('red').getColor('blue').getColor('green').log() // Must be "red blue green"

getColor('yellow').log() // Must be "yellow"
```

What I decided to do is to store the color in the prototype and then check if it is existing. If we already have color then we append a new color to it.
However, my function became a singleton because of it. I don’t really understand how I achieved this, but `getColor.prototype.color` is passed from one call to another…

```
getColor('red').getColor('blue').getColor('green').log() // "red blue green" - GOOD!
```

```
getColor('yellow').log() // "red blue green yellow" - WAT?
```

As far as I understand - if I modify the proto once then it remains modified.

What I want to achieve is to be able to chain the function with itself

**and**

the colors should be stacked only if I call the function from itself.
So basically some logic that will be triggered only in  `getColor().getColor` case but not in `getColor()`

Comment: You're mixing object oriented concepts (chaining) with functional programming. The first thing you need to do is realize that chaining is an object oriented design pattern. You therefore need to write two functions: the factory `getColor` which should return a `Color` object and the color object should have  a method `Color.prototype.getColor` which is the chainable method. I'd generally consider having two different functions having the same name as bad design but how the API looks is up to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First thing first I'm trying to implement a function that can be chained with itself.

Let's translate that: You're trying to write a function that *returns an object instance* that has a function (a "method") that again returns an object instance, etc.pp.

Functions that create object instances are commonly called factory functions.

```
function getColor(color) {
    return new Color(color);
}
```

Now `Color` instances could have a method such as `add()` which adds a new color to the current color. For a fluent interface (or "chaining"), this again needs to return an object instance. For now, let's return the same object.

```
function Color(color) {
    this.color = color;
    this.add = function (color) {
       this.color += ' ' + color;
       return this;
    }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
getColor('red').add('green').add('blue');    // => now contains 'red green blue';
new Color('red').add('green').add('blue');   // => same thing
```

If you don't want to mutate the `Color` instance, convert `.add()` to another factory:

```
function Color(color) {
    this.color = color;
    this.add = function (color) {
       return new Color(this.color + ' ' + color);
    }
}
```

Usage does not change.

> the colors should be stacked only if I call the function from itself

I have avoided calling the stand-alone factory `getColor()` the same as the class-internal factory `.add()` because they do different things. But `.add()` already fulfills that requirement.

In order to avoid having a separate `.add()` on every class instance, let's move it to the prototype. Let's also include a fluent `.log()` method and, as a variation, a class method `.get()` that replaces the stand-alone the `getColor()` factory:

```
function Color(color) {
    this.color = color;
}
Color.prototype.add = function (color) {
    return new Color(this.color + ' ' + color);
};
Color.prototype.log = function () {
    console.log(this.color);
    return this;
};
Color.get = function (color) {
    return new Color(color);
};
```

Usage:

```
Color.get('red').log().add('green').log().add('blue').log();
new Color('red').log().add('green').log().add('blue').log();
```

If you prefer the ES6 class syntax:

```
class Color {
    constructor (color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    add (color) {
        return new Color(this.color + ' ' + color);
    }
    log () {
        console.log(this.color);
        return this;
    }
    static get(color) {
        return new Color(color);
    }
}
```

TypeScript typings have nothing to do with the issue at hand, so I left them out.

Comment: I’m still looking for the final approach I would like to use in my actual (not sample) code. But your answer gave me a lot better understanding of some things. So I’ll accept it. Thank you!

Comment: @anotheruser Ultimately it's up to you how you design this, there is no One True Answer.